# how can I transfer data between php pages?

Tags: php

There is a page: login.php

I try to receive username and password via form.

login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Giris Yap</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" name="form" method="post" action="welcome.php">
            <table width="275" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td width="103">user; name: </td>
                    <td width="156"><label>
                            <input type="text" name= "name" />
                        </label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>password:</td>
                    <td><label>
                            <input type="password" name="textfield2" />
                        </label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p><label>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" />
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="reset" />
                </label>
            </p>
        </form>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

After that I want to lead my page into welcome.php and says welcome ...name... But it does not work. Can anyone help me.

welcome.php:

```
<?php 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
echo "Welcome"$name; 
?>
```

Comment: Fix your syntax errors: `echo "Welcome" . $name;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

Always make use of `isset()` construct in this context. Since we know that your `<form>` method has action POST, you can make use of the `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "Welcome $name"; 
}
?>
```

Also, you are missing the submit button code on your **`<form>`** , Do like this

```
<form id="form1" name="form" method="post" action="welcome.php">
    <table width="275" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="103">User; Name: </td>
            <td width="156"><label>
                    <input type="text" name= "name" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
                </label></td>
        </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: do I need to add any php cpde into login.php form page ?  because there is no php codes in login.php.

Comment: @user3037527, You need to add the submit button, please see the edited code. No PHP code needed in your login.php in this context.

Comment: I have edit login.php code as above. but  there is nothing in this page about <php ... ?>   Do I need to add some php codes into login.php page ?

Comment: What do you get in the screen ?

Comment: blank screen. login.php pages moves to welcome.php page but welcome.php page shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is all depends on the method you have specified in your form. If your form `method="post"` then you need  retrieve like `$_POST['name']`

and if your form `method="GET"` then you need retrieve like `$_GET['name']`

```
$name = $_POST['name']; // you have used method='post'
echo "Welcome" .$name;
```

Also,  `$_REQUEST` - An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Don't forget, because $_REQUEST is a different variable than $_GET and $_POST, it is treated as such in PHP -- modifying $_GET or $_POST elements at runtime will not affect the ellements in $_REQUEST, nor vice versa.

e.g:

```
<?php

 $_GET['foo'] = 'a';
 $_POST['bar'] = 'b';
 var_dump($_GET); // Element 'foo' is string(1) "a"
 var_dump($_POST); // Element 'bar' is string(1) "b"
 var_dump($_REQUEST); // Does not contain elements 'foo' or 'bar'

?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try it.

```
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['name']))
   {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      echo "Welcome ". $name; 
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
?php
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
   $name = $_POST['name']; 
   echo "Welcome $name"; 
}
else
{
    echo "Name not set";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
// let us make sure we have a post value. we will use isset to make sure it's set.
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
// you should scrub the $name value before displaying.  Never display or work with
// raw post values.
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "Welcome "; 

// what if they didn't really put in a name?
// maybe only show it if it's longer than 2?
if (strlen($str) > '2')
echo $name; 
}
}
else {
// we don't have a post value?  You should redirect with error message or something.
}

?>
```